# Problem defering HTML Print

Tags: javascript

I'm printing a webpage using the javascript

```
window.print();
```

whether enclosed in a document.ready or onload event inline the print dialog often pops up before the content is ready.

Ive tried this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        setTimeout(printPage(),200000);
        function printPage()
        {
            window.print();
        }
    });
```

To no avail, can anyone suggest a way to reliably defer printing until the content is ready

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing the **return value** of `printPage` to `setTimeout`. You have to omit the parenthesis:

```
setTimeout(printPage,200000);
```

<sub>I hope you know that 200000ms are more than 3 minutes</sub>

`printPage()` will call the function.

Or if you want to call when everything is loaded, call the function in the [`load` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.onload) handler:

> The load event fires at the end of the document loading process. At this point, all of the objects in the document are in the DOM, and all the images and sub-frames have finished loading.

```
window.onload = function() {
    window.print();
};

// or if you want to use jQuery
$(window).load(function() {
    window.print();
});
```

Comment: Yeah I know its a silly time It was just for testing purposes (using an out there time and the print dialog still coming up was telling me something was definitely wrong

Answer (score 0):

so you should be use window.onload instead of document.ready
and i think you should be use setTimeout("printPage()",200000);

//setTimeout([string],200000);

Comment: Given the code above this won't even work as `printPage` is not in global scope. You should avoid passing strings to `setTimeout`.